# Copy-paste to input text submits control/non-printable characters to web server & database

Tags: asp.net, .net

I've just realized that on some forms users do copy-paste of data (for instance copy from Word/Excel into input[text]). This data is submitted and then saved to database.

Control characters and non-printable characters are saved and user doesn't see it, but I have some file reports / outbounds in application, and these contain wierd data , for instnce:

> GBPÂ ï¿½..Â the

is a result of this (hex):

> 37 37 7c 47 42 50 **c2 a0  e2 80 93 c2 a0** 74 68 65

Is there any way to filter out these special characters on global level?

Answer (score 0):

You have several utility methods attached to the char type (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/424s1h3z.aspx).

For example, to cleanup the control characters you may use linq this way :

```
public string CleanupControlsChars(string inString)
{
    return new string(inString.Where(ch => !char.IsControl(ch)).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. although I know that char class has this helper methods. What I was looking forward to hear, is a solution on form/request level - more global. I don't want to call CleanupControlsChars on every TextBox.Text

Comment: @dragonfly ok, thx for explaining the question. Best hint I can give you could be to look in the Request.Filter direction to cleanup the entry stream. I use it on the Response side it to cleanup output (to replace some ill-encoded chars)